# How can I make a series expansion of $F(x) = \int_0^x \exp -{(t^2)}\ dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

$$F(x) = \int_0^x \exp -{(t^2)}\ dt$$
We need to find the series expansion for $F(x)$.

I tried differentiating $F(x)$ but couldn't establish certain pattern so that Taylor series formation may help..

Kindly help !!

Comment: What about the FTC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the expansion for $\exp(t)$, hence the expansion for $\exp(-t^2/2)$. Plug in, integrate, and by happy: $$\exp(t) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{t^n}{n!} \implies \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right) = \sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{t^{2n}}{2^nn!},$$ so we get: $$F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)2^nn!}.$$

**Edit:** for the edited question with $\exp(-t^2)$ the same reasoning works. It is in fact easier.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
F'(x) &= \exp - \frac {x^2}2 = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-x^2/2)^n}{n!}
\\ &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} x^{2n}
\\ \implies F(x) &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} 
\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
\end{align}